# About the Christoffel Symbols

Tags: tensors, general-relativity

I have a quick but important question about the concept of the Christoffel Symbols, and it is if you can apply another tensor rather than the metric tensor to find the Christoffel Symbols.

I am trying to solve the covariant derivative of the contravariant stress-energy tensor, but I do not know if for the Christoffel Symbols I have to apply the stress-energy tensor to them or the metric tensor I was given. It is:

\begin{align*}
\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\rho}=\frac{1}{2}T^{\rho a}\left(
\partial_{\mu}T_{\nu a}+\partial_{\nu}T_{\mu a}-\partial_aT_{\mu\nu}\right)
\end{align*}

or just

\begin{align*}
\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\rho}=\frac{1}{2}g^{\rho a}\left(
\partial_{\mu}g_{\nu a}+\partial_{\nu}g_{\mu a}-\partial_ag_{\mu\nu}\right)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\Gamma$s that get along nicely with the standard covariant (not "contravariant") derivative are always given by
$$
\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\rho}=\frac{1}{2}g^{\rho a}\left(
\partial_{\mu}g_{\nu a}+\partial_{\nu}g_{\mu a}-\partial_ag_{\mu\nu}\right)
$$
and not that other one. These are the quantities that measure how the coordinate system on your space curves, which is then used in the formula for the covariant derivative. And to measure how the coordinate system curves, the (components of the) metric tensor is the only quantity that matters.

Be careful with that $a$ index in there, however. It is a convention in relativity to denote indices that range over all four dimensions with Greek letters and indices that only range over the three spacial dimensions with Latin letters. You want all four here, so I would, to be on the safe side, use a Greek letter such as $\sigma$ instead of $a$.

Comment: Thanks! My fault, I meant covariant derivative, but I was referring to the contravariant stress-energy tensor, so I mixed things up but already edited!